# Haskell, sequential program flow?

Tags: haskell

Apologies, as this may seem a very weird question. All of my experience in haskell has been writing functions which usually recursively progress (and some data element decreases with each iteration). However, I have a set of functions which each do some processing on a piece of data and I wanted my calling method to contain each stage, for example

(Pseudo code)

```
myFunc1 :: Something1 -> Something2

execute myFunc1 Something1
.
execute myFunc2
.
execute myFunc3
.
execute myFunc4
.

return Something2
```

But I am unsure if this is even possible? Do I simply have to have something silly like:

`myFunc4(myFunc3(myFunc2(MyFunc1(Something1))))` ?

EDIT: The above line cannot be right, surely!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the function call operator [`$`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-Base.html#%24):

```
myFunc4 $ myFunc3 $ myFunc2 $ myFunc1 $ Something1
```

Or function composition:

```
myFunc4 . myFunc3 . myFunc2 . myFunc1 $ Something1
```

Or `let`:

```
let x = myFunc1 Something1 in
let y = myFunc2 x in
let z = myFunc3 y in
myFunc4 z
```

Comment: Or, more idiomatically (for unknown reason, maybe it just looks nicer): `myFunc4 . myFunc3 . myFunc2 . myFunc1 $ Something1`.

Comment: Or the composition operator `(.)`, `myFunc4 . myFunc3 . myFunc2 . myFunc1 $ Something1`. Damn, I'm just a too slow typist!

Comment: what if myfunc2 only happened, dependent on a conditional (IF) clause?

Comment: @user997112: use a `let` combined with an `if`-`then`-`else`, or define a custom combinator. Or put the conditional logic inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep left-to-right reading order, you can define

```
(.>) = flip (.) -- are those in standard library somewhere?
($>) = flip ($)

myComplex = Something1 $> myFunc1 .> myFunc2 .> myFunc3 .> myFunc4
```